# Conflict between dataset and catalog

Tags: python, xml, dataset, rdf, ckan

I am trying to add some tags inside the dataset definition on my XML. According to the European Data Portal de structure I must follow for the tag

```
<foaf:Agent rdf:about="URI/of/the/publisher">
   <foaf:name xml:lang="es"> Name of the publisher</foaf:name>
</foaf:Agent>

<dct:publisher rdf:resource=”URI/of/the/publisher”>
```

Right now inside my dcat:Dataset I can only add the dct:publisher, missing the two other tags.

In my code I have asigned the name as a literal and for the URI an URIref since it must be values for an RDF.

```
g = self.g
g.add((dataset_ref, RDF.type, DCAT.Dataset))
publishers = dataset_dict.get(dhc.EXPORT_AVAILABLE_PUBLISHERS, {})
organization_id = dataset_dict.get('publisher')
if organization_id in publishers:
    publisher = publishers.get(organization_id)
else:
    publisher = []
    org = h.get_organization(organization_id, False)
    publisher = [org.get('title'), None, None]
    if org and org['extras']:
        for extra in org.get('extras'):
            if extra and 'key' in extra and extra['key'] == dhc.ORG_ID_:
                notation = extra.get('value')
                publisher[1] = dhc.PUBLISHER_PREFIX + notation
                publisher[2] = notation
            publishers[organization_id] = publisher
            dataset_dict[dhc.EXPORT_AVAILABLE_PUBLISHERS] = publishers
        if publisher:
            # self._add_resource_list_triple(dataset_ref, DCT.publisher, publisher[1], publisher[0], None, None, publisher[2]) 
            EDP_publisher = URIRef(publisher[1])
            g.add((dataset_ref, DCT.publisher, EDP_publisher))
            g.add((dataset_ref, FOAF.Agent, EDP_publisher))
            g.add((EDP_publisher, FOAF.name, Literal(publisher[0])))
```

So everytime I use the g.add with FOAF.name and FOAF.Agent, it sends my tag out of the dataset tag (dcat:Dataset) and transforms it from about to a resource definition.
I am feeling it could be a conflict of code. Where could I be making the wrong defition?

Updated:
After giving it more tries, I've found that the issued for the structure to not get into the "main tag" is a conflict because of the use of "RDF.type" definition since the main structure is `g.add((dataset_ref, RDF.type, DCAT.Dataset))` and when I try to create it a parent and child tag, the parent get duplicate with the main tag since it gets the same values, since I found in the documentation that if the child structure doesn't find on the parent a "RDF.type", it will generate it automatically by calling it "rdf:Description"

I only managed to get the followed structured even though, it's not what I need to get.

```
      <dcat:Dataset rdf:about="URI-ref">
        <dct:description xml:lang="es"> Description of the dataset </dct:description>
        <dct:title xml:lang="en">Title of dataset</dct:title>
        <dct:publisher rdf:resource="URI-ref"/>
      </dcat:Dataset>
  <foaf:Agent rdf:about="URI-ref">
    <foaf:name>Name of the publisher</foaf:name>
  </foaf:Agent>
```

I can't manage to add the Foaf:Agent and foaf:name inside the dcat:Dataset.

Comment: `g.add((dataset_ref, FOAF.Agent, EDP_publisher))` -> is there a reason for using `foaf:Agent` as a property? I mean, it's clearly a class in the FOAF vocabulary, isn't it?

Comment: I also don't understand what you mean by "outside of the dataset" - you're just adding triples to an RDF graph.

Comment: Foaf:agent is used cause the European Data Portal declared that tag like that.

Comment: By outside of the dataset, I mean:

`<dcat:Dataset rdf:about="URIref">
<dct:title xml:lang="en">Title</dct:title>
<dct:language rdf:resource="URIlanguage"/>
<dcat:distribution rdf:resource="URIref"/>
<dct:publisher rdf:resource="URIpublisher"/>
<foaf:Agent rdf:resource="URIpublisher"/>
<dct:description xml:lang="en">TEXT.</dct:description>
</dcat:Dataset>
<foaf:name>Name publisher</foaf:name>`

I'm trying to get
<foaf:Agent rdf:resource="URIpublisher">
    <foaf:name>Name publisher</foaf:name>
</foaf:name>
Inside of the <dcat:Dataset>

Comment: again, `foaf:Agent` is **not** a property ... and reagrding your other question, it don't see why this matters. It's just the XML serialization of RDF, semantically it doesn't matter.

Comment: The problem isn't about the `foaf:Agent` it's about the RDFlib on the Graph() allowing the tag has a sub-class

Comment: it's not a problem nor a bug. It's just how `rdflib` serializes the data in RDF/XML syntax. It doesn't matter, the RDF is valid. You can try `pretty-xml` as format - if this doesn't help, you can't do anything

Comment: Like I know the property you mean should be RDF.type but that valued is already taken but the biggest tag `g.add((dataset_ref, RDF.type, DCAT.Dataset))`